# Only one default export allowed per module

Tags: reactjs

Errors prevented startup:

While building for web.browser:
imports/ui/App.jsx:62: Only one default export allowed per module. (62:0)

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // setting up the state
    this.state = { players: [] };
}

App.propTypes = {
  players: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('players');

  return {
    players: Players.find({}, {sort: { name: 1}}).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

Comment: Pretty self explanatory? You have `export default` twice. What is your question?

Comment: Yes what exactly do you wanna do? You want multiple exports in one file? If so don't use default keyword and import using {}

Answer (score 4):

You file can have only `one default export` and `zero or more named export`. In your case you have two default exports resulting in the error.

You can change one to them to a named export

like

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // setting up the state
    this.state = { players: [] };
}

App.propTypes = {
  players: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('players');

  return {
    players: Players.find({}, {sort: { name: 1}}).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

later if you want to `import App` you can do so like

```
import {App} from './path/to/App';
```

Comment: Thanks! Keeping only a single default export statement in the file, fixed my issue.